# Using setDate with jQueryUi datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to set the date of another datepicker exactly 1 year on from the original datepicker on close.

I have the following code:

```
$("#myDatepicker1").datepicker({
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
$("#myDatepicker2").datepicker("setDate", dateText +1y);
}
});
```

As you can guess this isn't working.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Richard

Comment: have u found the answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
d = $("#myDatepicker1").datepicker("getDate");
$("#myDatepicker2").datepicker("setDate", new Date(d.getFullYear()+1,d.getMonth(),d.getDate()));
```

EDIT:

This is the solution to add one year, just to make sure that this is the piece which was missing right?! the on close it`s working fine right?!

Comment: Yeah, the onClose is fine. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  I.e. i select 13/04/2011 and myDatepicker2 sets the date as 03/04/2012.  It's close but not right.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: That's it working now. It should be d.getDate() and not d.getDay(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: i was just going to add getDate, @RichardL thanx for your attention :)

Comment: Is there a method to get the end date of selected year?  Instead of 01/01/2017, I want 12/31/2016.