# jQuery .val(MyVar) not putting value into field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to put today's date into a textbox, using .blur().  I am getting the date into my variable, but it is not setting in the field.

```
   <%  String ClearDate = String.Empty;
       if (DateTime.Now.Year - Model.ClearedDate.Year < 20)
       ClearDate = Model.ClearedDate.ToShortDateString(); %>

    <%: Html.TextBox("ClearedDate", ClearDate)%>

    var today = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
    $("#FederalApprovalDate").blur(function (){
        var fed = $("#FederalApprovalDate").val();
        var state = $("#StateApprovalDate").val();
        if (fed && state)
        {   
            $("#IsPreCleared").val(true);
            $("#IsCleared").val(true);
            $("#ClearedDate").val(today);
        }
    });
```

The IsCleared and IsPreCleared flags are setting to true, but the ClearedDate is staying empty.  Can you see what I am missing?

Editted to add cleareddate input code.

Comment: What element is `cleareddate`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using JQuery UI Datepicekr, use

```
$("#ClearedDate").datepicker("setDate", today);
```

find a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692048/using-setdate-with-jqueryui-datepicker)

documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: Tried it, no go.  I think it was something to do with the way the ClearedDate textbox is setup, like the new value can't get it because of the if statement before the textbox. Could that be it?

Comment: Reading the datepicker docs I see that you have to call the .datepicker() method on a div, I thought it worked also on an <input/>.. have you already tried to use a div?